# Gnome Builder Run Error

Tags: compiling, c, ide, gnome-builder

Hello community I'm the newbiest Ubuntu user ever. I'm also Computer Science student migrating to this operation system and looking for clean IDE to build my algorithms. I found one called "Builder" but it is not working properly. I faced two errors, first one was saying to install `autopoint` after that the second one showed up saying it:

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: running: autopoint --force
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force 
configure.ac:102: error: m4_defn: undefined macro: LT_PACKAGE_VERSION
m4/libtool.m4:40: LT_PREREQ is expanded from...
configure.ac:102: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

Any ideas to solve this error?

Comment: (1) what version of Ubuntu and what version of `gnome-builder`? (2) what instructions are you following? (3) do you really need to build from source (it's [available from the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome-builder) since 16.04)

Comment: Hi @steeldriver, my gnome-builder is "3.24.1-0ubuntu1" and OS version: 17.04... any idea?

Comment: Sorry I thought you were trying to **build** `gnome-builder` - if you already have the pre-built `gnome-builder` 3.24.1-0ubuntu1 from the repository, what exactly are you trying to build from source?

Comment: @steeldriver Just some homework to be done... Trying to write them, matrixes and so on... But not even an simple Hello World is running... The error mentioned above always show up.

Comment: Having the same problem with GNOME Builder in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04. A simple Hello World program won't work because of this error (after making a new C++ project).

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 17.04 `gnome-builder` package has dependency problem for autotools.

To fix this you need to add two packages more: `autopoint`, `libtool-bin`.

Execute this in terminal:

```
sudo apt install autopoint libtool-bin
```

In your case, you have installed `autopoint` already, so just install `libtool-bin`.